# Gulp-kss issues

Tags: gulp, less, gulp-less, kss

I am trying to get `gulp-kss` working on my project, but I am encountering issues when I try to run my task. I get the following error message:

```
[12:07:28] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Websites/company/project-uiapp/gulpfile.js
[12:07:28] Starting 'generate-sc'...
[12:07:28] Finished 'generate-sc' after 20 ms
fs.js:549
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Josua/Documents/Websites/company/project-uiapp/node_modules/gulp-kss/node_modules/kss/lib/template/index.html'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
at Stream.endStream (/Users/Josua/Documents/Websites/company/project-uiapp/node_modules/gulp-kss/index.js:42:27)
at _end (/Users/Josua/Documents/Websites/company/project-uiapp/node_modules/through/index.js:65:9)
at Stream.stream.end (/Users/Josua/Documents/Websites/company/project-uiapp/node_modules/through/index.js:74:5)
at DestroyableTransform.onend (/Users/Josua/Documents/Websites/company/project-uiapp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:523:10)
at DestroyableTransform.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
at /Users/Josua/Documents/Websites/company/project-uiapp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:965:16
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:389:13)
```

How would I resolve this error? I have been searching Google and Stackoverflow but I have not found a solution yet. I am basing my solution off this [gulp-kss](https://github.com/PhilJ/gulp-kss). I have included my `gulp` task below:

```
...
// Generate styleguide with templates
gulp.task('generate-sc', function() {

gulp.src(['build-less'])
.pipe(gulpkss({
    overview: __dirname + '/styles/styleguide.md'
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('styleguide/'));

 // Concat and compile all your styles for correct rendering of the styleguide.
gulp.src('./src/less/styles.less')
.pipe(less())
.pipe(gulpconcat('styles/style.css'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('styleguide/'));
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue. I had to add `kss` to my `package.json`. I figured it would of been included with `gulp-kss`.